# How to implement a python script into an HTML site, so the user can type in input using the python script

Tags: html, python-3.x

I have a python script ( **a random number generator** ) and I want to create a site using `HTML` that uses the `python` script to give an input to the user which produces the random password. I am fairly new to programming and am not sure how to do this.

This is my code here

```
import random

chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyz !@#$'

number = input("Number of passwords? - ")
number = int(number)

length = input("Password length - ")
length = int(length)

for f in range(number):
  password = ''
  for c in range(length):
    password += random.choice(chars)
  print(password)
```

Comment: Your question doesn't  clearly convey what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I want a text box to appear, than it would give a question "Number of passwords? - " from the python script and the user gives an input, than the python script displays the random password in the text box on the html website. I hope that clears it up a bit.

Comment: I don't think it can be done in python but I have provided an answer below that does the same thing using Javascript. See if that helps

Comment: There is not really a way to implement python with html because python wasn't built for that, you probably would need a lot of complex modules, however, Javascript would probably be your solution its similar to python in the complexity. Basically its fairly easy to transition.

Comment: Look into Django or Flask, preferably the latter as it's a bit more comprehensive.

Comment: For web application with python, you may use [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/)

Comment: is there a way that i can use a back-end sucha s django or flask to do this?

Comment: Its probably better to go with javascript as that's the main reason javascript was developed - with web development in mind. Maybe there exists some library that could allow you to do in python, but JS will always allow for more flexibility and should be your go-to language for web development. If you are not looking to do much except the thing you mentioned in the question. You can use the below answer I provided . I have basically converted the python code into its JS equivalent

Comment: The purpose of python web dev libs was to allow web dev without the constraint of using js, and allow an arguably better framework. That's not to say that js doesn't have good frameworks, for all sorts of usecases, but js native libs are slightly lacking. I recommend you look into those framworks due to the fact you're familiar with python, and I am of the mind that js shouldn't have such a monopoly on WD the way it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not exactly sure if you can do it on a website with python. There might be libraries that allow you to use python for the same but I don't think you can directly do it. However, you can do it using javascript as follows -

```js
const chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyz !@#$'
let numberOfPasswords = 0;

function passNum(value) {
  numberOfPasswords = value;
}

let lengthOfPassword = 0

function passLen(value) {
  lengthOfPassword = value;
}

let res = '';

function displayResult() {

  for (let i = 0; i < numberOfPasswords; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < lengthOfPassword; j++) {
      res += chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(chars.length))]
    }
    res+='\n'
  }
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = res;
}

document.getElementById("getPass").addEventListener("click", displayResult);
```

```css
input,textarea{
  width:80%
}
```

```html
<label for="fname">Number of passwords? - </label><br>
<input type="text" id="passnum" name="passnum" placeholder='Enter numer  of Passwords to be generated' onChange='passNum(this.value)'><br><br>
<label for="lname">Password length - </label><br>
<input type="text" id="passlen" name="passlen" placeholder='Enter desired length of Password' onChange='passLen(this.value)'><br><br>
<b>GENERATED PASSWORDS =></b><br>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id='result' placeholder='Generated passwords will be displayed here one on each line'>
</textarea><br>
<button id='getPass'>Generate password</button>
```

Comment: This answer is definitely useful, and it works great, but I do see that it should be encouraged for the OA to use a Python lib for this usecase, as that is more what they were looking for and more broadly fits the tags

Comment: when i put this code in Note Pad and open it in chrome it doesn't work.

Comment: @FrancescoErichsen you have to put the javascript code inside script tags - `<script>` js code `</script>`. You can put this inside the `<head>` or right before the ending body tag

Comment: i added that in with the proper html format and nothing shows up on the page?

Comment: @FrancescoErichsen there must be some error in the way you have written code or while saving file/opening in browser or something. If it's working here, it must work when you save it in a notepad as html and open in browser

Comment: @Abhishek all of my other html code works, once i put the js code in the <script>...</script> it disappeared. and when it wasn't in that it didn't even work.

Answer (score 0):

A purely Pythonic way, using Flask. Execute the code, open your browser, head to `localhost:8080`, enter inputs and press Go.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
import random
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    print('Verified Request made to Base Domain')
    resp = jsonify(status=200)
    return "\
    <form type='GET' action='/result'>\
    <label for='number'>Number</label>\
    <input type='text' name='number' />\
    <label for='length'>Length</label>\
    <input type='text' name='length' />\
    <input type='submit' value='Go' />\
    </form>\
    "
@app.route('/result', methods=['GET'])
def run():
    number = int(request.args['number'])
    length = int(request.args['length'])
    passwords = []
    chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyz !@#$'
    for f in range(number):
        password = ''
        for c in range(length):
            password += random.choice(chars)
        passwords.append(password)
    return jsonify(passwords= passwords)

app.run('localhost', 8080, app)
```